# Htaccess 301 redirect from en urls to main urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I created a multilanguage site with URLs that have language codes in them.

It looks like this:

```
sub1.example.com/en/
sub1.example.com/en/this-is-page-in-english
sub1.example.com/de/
sub1.example.com/de/this-is-page-in-german
sub1.example.com/pl/this-is-page-in-polish
sub2.example.com/en/
```

etc.

Because English is the main language, I would like to redirect those URLs to these URLs:

```
sub1.example.com/
sub1.example.com/this-is-page-in-english
sub1.example.com/de/
sub1.example.com/de/this-is-page-in-german
sub1.example.com/pl/this-is-page-in-polish
sub2.example.com/
```

In other words, redirect all English pages to the main pages, for all subdomains.

Thanks

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess rules file, along with complete details of which url should be served with which file in backend to make your question clear, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rule to redirect `/en` URLs to the main sub domain

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

Don't forget to replace `example.com` with your `yourdomain.com` .